# Illegal IndexedColor index: 0

Tags: c#, npoi

I am trying to convert xlsx file to html using below code but i am getting "**Illegal IndexedColor index: 0**" exception.

```
   XSSFWorkbook xssfwb;
   var fileName = @"c:\temp\test.xlsx";
   using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
    xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    ExcelToHtmlConverter excelToHtmlConverter = new ExcelToHtmlConverter();

    //set output parameter
    excelToHtmlConverter.OutputColumnHeaders = false;
    excelToHtmlConverter.OutputHiddenColumns = true;
    excelToHtmlConverter.OutputHiddenRows = true;
    excelToHtmlConverter.OutputLeadingSpacesAsNonBreaking = false;
    excelToHtmlConverter.OutputRowNumbers = false;
    excelToHtmlConverter.UseDivsToSpan = true;

    //process the excel file
    excelToHtmlConverter.ProcessWorkbook(xssfwb);

    //output the html file
    excelToHtmlConverter.Document.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "html"));
   }
```

please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According [this issue](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues/621) it's a bug in NPOI library. I guess that the exception can be thrown if an excel file contains text with color other than black.